# Powershell status information

Tags: powershell, status, diagnostics

What is the prescribed method for display status or progress information to a user from a Powershell script? For example, "Connecting to database..." Normally I'd print to STDERR.

Powershell has a Write-Progress cmdlet, but that's for a progress bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Write-Host cmdlet.  The strings displayed via write host go directly to the console and are not considered part of the output stream.  For example:

```
function foo {
    Write-Host "Entering foo"
    "Hello World"
    Get-Date
    [Math]::Pi
    Write-Host "Exiting foo"
}

PS> $results = foo
Entering foo
Exiting foo
PS> $OFS = ', '
PS> "Outputting results: $results"
Outputting results: Hello World, 11/05/2009 18:55:24, 3.14159265358979
```

Note that the output from Write-Host appears immediately on the host and does not *not* become part of the output stream (or in this case - output of function foo).

Comment: theres also write-verbose and write-debug for extra information